# Socket Programming: Server/Clients and Thread Usage

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcpclient

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Socket Server";
        Console.WriteLine("Listening for client messages");

        Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                         SocketType.Stream,
                                         ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPAddress serverIp = IPAddress.Any;
        IPEndPoint serverEP = new IPEndPoint(serverIp, 8000);

        SocketPermission socketPermission = new SocketPermission(NetworkAccess.Accept,
                                                                 TransportType.Tcp,
                                                                 "127.0.0.1", 8000);

        serverSocket.Bind(serverEP);
        serverSocket.Listen(2);


        while(true)
        {
            //Socket connection = serverSocket.Accept();

            connection = serverSocket.Accept();

            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(MultiUser));           
            clientThread.Start(connection);


        }
    }

    public static void MultiUser(object connection)
    {

        byte[] serverBuffer = new byte[10025];
        string message = string.Empty;

        int bytes = ((Socket)connection).Receive(serverBuffer, serverBuffer.Length, 0);
        message += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(serverBuffer, 0, bytes);
        Console.WriteLine(message);

        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.Client = ((Socket)connection);
        IntPtr handle = client.Client.Handle;



    }
```

I want to write a chat program which has one server and 2 clients. The problem is that, I can not direct the message sent from the client1 to client2 via the server. How can the server distinguish threads so that it can send the received message from client1 to client2?

Comment: A simple way would be to create a `Message` class that had fields for things like `to`, `from`, `message`, etc.... Then send this object to your server. Your server could then read the `to` field and send it along to the other client.

Comment: You need to keep a list (a hash, a vector) of connected clients, iterator over it, and send to all *ther* clients. Since you are using threads, you need to provide some mutual exclusion while accessing that list.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen If both clients are using "127.0.0.1", how can I distinguish them by creating a Message class ?

Comment: You should use async sockets instead of creating your own threads--much more scalable.

Answer (score 1):

Each client has their own handle. You can access this via the **Handle** property. For example:

```
TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
IntPtr handle = client.Client.Handle; //returns a handle to the connection
```

Then all you need to do is store this in a hashtable, and iterate through it, looking for available data. When you detect data on the wire for one of the connections, then save it and retransmit it to the other clients in the table.

Remember to make sure that you make this multithreaded so a listen request on one client does not block any send or receive functions on other clients!

I've added some code here you should be able to work with (tested it out on my system)

```
private void HandleClients(object newClient)
        {
            //check to see if we are adding a new client, or just iterating through existing clients
            if (newClient != null)
            {
                TcpClient newTcpClient = (TcpClient)newClient;

                //add this client to our list
                clientList.Add(newTcpClient.Client.Handle, newTcpClient);
                Console.WriteLine("Adding handle: " + newTcpClient.Client.Handle);  //for debugging
            }

            //iterate through existing clients to see if there is any data on the wire
            foreach (TcpClient tc in clientList.Values)
            {
                if (tc.Available > 0)
                {
                    int dataSize = tc.Available;
                    Console.WriteLine("Received data from: " + tc.Client.Handle); //for debugging

                    string text = GetNetworkString(tc.GetStream());

                    //and transmit it to everyone else
                    foreach (TcpClient otherClient in clientList.Values)
                    {
                        if (tc.Client.Handle != otherClient.Client.Handle)
                        {
                            Send(otherClient.GetStream(), text);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void Send(NetworkStream ns, string data)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] bdata = GetBytes(data, Encoding.ASCII);
                ns.Write(bdata, 0, bdata.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected string GetNetworkString(NetworkStream ns)
        {
            if (ns.CanRead)
            {
                string receivedString;
                byte[] b = GetNetworkData(ns);

                receivedString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
                log.Info("Received string: " + receivedString);

                return receivedString;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }

        protected byte[] GetNetworkData(NetworkStream ns)
        {
            if (ns.CanRead)
            {
                log.Debug("Data detected on wire...");
                byte[] b;
                byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                int numberOfBytesRead = 0;

                // Incoming message may be larger than the buffer size.
                do
                {
                    numberOfBytesRead = ns.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
                    ms.Write(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
                }
                while (ns.DataAvailable);

                //and get the full message
                b = new byte[(int)ms.Length];
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                ms.Read(b, 0, (int)ms.Length);
                ms.Close();

                return b;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
```

You will want to call **HandleClients** from a main thread that checks to see if there are any pending requests or not, and runs on a loop.